# Jquery draggable image drop to that div where the left-upper corner is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Droppable divs:

```
<div id="invContainer" style="width:100px; height:100px;>
  <div id="inv_0-0" class="inventory" style="position: relative; float:left; width:50px; height:50px; background-color: #fff;"></div>
  <div id="inv_1-0" class="inventory" style="position: relative; float:left; width:50px; height:50px; background-color: #000;"></div>
  <div id="inv_0-1" class="inventory" style="position: relative; float:left; width:50px; height:50px; background-color: #000;"></div>
  <div id="inv_1-1" class="inventory" style="position: relative; float:left; width:50px; height:50px; background-color: #fff;"></div>
</div>
```

I have some draggable images, if i drop it to this container the image drops where the images center was. But i would like it to drop where the images upper left corner is. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

First see if JQuery draggable has a standard snap-to-position function.
Oterwise you'll haveto "move" the image on drop to the position you want.
With a little math like so:

```
function ondrop_move(obj) {
    w = obj.width();
    h = obj.height();
    new_top = obj.position().top + (h / 2);
    new_left = obj.position().left + (w / 2)
    obj.css('left', new_left);
    obj.css('top', new_top);
}
```